# Protocol buffer code compiles for iOS simulator but not device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using [github.com/apple/swift-protobuf tag 0.9.904](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/releases/tag/0.9.904) and [github.com/grpc/grpc-swift tag 0.1.12](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/releases/tag/0.1.12) with Xcode in my iOS app. I am also using the same versions with protoc to compile my .proto file.

The app works fine in the iOS simulator but when I try to run the app on my device I get compile errors on the following bit of generated code in `myapp.pb.swift`:

```
// If the compiler emits an error on this type, it is because this file
// was generated by a version of the `protoc` Swift plug-in that is
// incompatible with the version of SwiftProtobuf to which you are linking.
// Please ensure that your are building against the same version of the API
// that was used to generate this file.
fileprivate struct _GeneratedWithProtocGenSwiftVersion: SwiftProtobuf.ProtobufAPIVersionCheck {
  struct _2: SwiftProtobuf.ProtobufAPIVersion_2 {}
  typealias Version = _2
}
```

The errors are

```
No type named 'ProtobufAPIVersion_2' in module 'SwiftProtobuf'
```

and

```
Type '_GeneratedWithProtocGenSwiftVersion' does not conform to protocol 'ProtobufAPIVersionCheck'
```

The comment on the piece of code causing the errors speaks for itself. However, if this is true, why does the app compile and run fine in the simulator? How can I get it to compile and run on my device as well?

Comment: Got the same error: no type named 'ProtobufAPIVersion_2' in module 'SwiftProtobuf'

Answer (score 0):

If this is still a problem for you, please file a GitHub issue on the [swift-protobuf](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf) project.